# Use Apex without DataTorrent RTS

Tags: apache-apex

Is it possible to use Apache Apex without DataTorrent RTS? It seems possible, but I couldn't find any tutorial about installing own build of apex sources(to run, you need at leas `apex` binary). I see that Apex CLI is available after build in `./engine/src/main/scripts/apex` but maybe there is some easier way than build it piece by piece.

Comment: Do you want to build your own Apex only Binary?

Comment: I want to build and start Apex application using only Apex :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to use Apex without DataTorrent RTS. You refer to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwRWBudOjg4 if you need step by step instructions.

You can also refer to the beginners guide: http://docs.datatorrent.com/beginner/

Answer (score 2):

Apex is also part of Apache Bigtop and there is a docker image available as well:

http://apex.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: I've seen this on apex website, but didn't notice that Bigtop is Apache project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are self-paced online courses too.

https://www.datatorrent.com/university/self-paced-online-courses/